# Pandas Replace_ column values

Tags: pandas, replace

[image]
Hello,
I am analyzing the next  dataset with this information .
[image]

The column ['program_number'] is an object but I want to change it to a integer colum.
I have tried to replace some values but it doesn´t work.
as you can see, some values like 6 is duplicate. like '6 ' and 6.
How can I resolve it? Many thanks

Comment: what are you going to do with the strings `3X` and `1X` ? converting them to int will fail.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Didn't see `1X` and `3X` at first.
If you need those numbers and just want to remove the `X` then:

```
df["Program"] = df["Program"].str.strip(" X").astype(int)
```

If there is data in the column which aren't numbers or which shouldn't be converted, you can use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='corece'`. If there are cells which can't be converted, you'll get `NaN`. Be aware that this will result in floating numbers.

```
df["Program"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Program"], errors="coerce")
```

**old**

You want to use `str.strip()` here, rather than replace.
Try this:

```
df1['program_number'] = df1['program_number'].str.strip().astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried it, but I still have some probelms wht the values '1A', '3X', etc